# Installing Exchange 2010 Error with Ipv6 disabled/enabled

Tags: exchange-2010

I've tried installing Exchange 2010 on Windows 2k8 R2. Following error occurred when installing Hub Transport Role.

> Hub Transport Role Failed
>   Error: The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); install-ExsetdataAtom -AtomName SharedMachineSettings -DomainController $RoleDomainController" was run: "An error occurred with error code '2147950640' and message 'There is no such object on the server.'.".
>   An error occurred with error code '2147950640' and message 'There is no such object on the server.'

I have tried installation with both IPV6 turned on and off. Both failed and both required me to do some magic to uninstall Exchange, and try installation again.

Feel free to shoot your ideas what can be done to resolve the error. In the end I will install HyperV and put Exchange 2010 on different server but that's not what the server owner wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update the Active Directory schema for Exchange 2010 as per this [Microsoft Exchange 2010 forum link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchange2010/thread/3b5394f6-8a63-4a84-9a3e-3e37dacfde48) with a similar problem?

See [Exchange Server 2010 Planning and Deployment - Prepare Active Directory and Domains](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125224.aspx) for more info on the steps.

Comment: I didn't, well I did in first 2 tries doing that ended with the same. And gui installation should have fixed this by itself

Comment: Actually i retried it once again after completely removing Exchange crippled features and it installed perfectly. I used manual steps as outlined in article to prepare Active Directory and as per your link.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference as Sim suggested:

It should be noted that GUI when you install Exchange 2010 teoretically executes setup /prepareAD for you but for me it never worked good and it crippled my installation so i had to use manual installation steps to remove Exchange 2010.

The best approach for installing Exchange to not have to deal with those errors is to prepare AD as per Sim suggestion and link. But to outline all steps I did that helped me here they are:

1. setup /pl (even thou it's not necessary)
2. setup /ps
3. setup /prepareAD /OrganizationName:"First Organization"
4. setup /prepareDomain (also not necessary)

and run installation again and ... all roles installed successfully.

So actually the GUI part of installation which is supposed to prepareAD is crippling installation and not always doing what it's supposed. Thanks Sim!

Hopes this little thread will help people solve problems with Exchange 2010 installation.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out MadBoy. Always best to read any of the Planning and Deployment guides before just relying on the GUI. They refer to using the command line setup tools to do the AD schema changes and don't mention the GUI.

Comment: Funny thing is Exchange MVP says he deployed dozen exchange 2010 and never used command line (always relied on GUI doing it by itself). Be smart here ;-)

Comment: Well he must have been very bloody lucky then.